# Transfer Data Between Two Children Using Qt Signals and Slots (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-signals

In Qt C++, I have a parent object MainWindow.  MainWindow has (among others) 2 member objects: vector, and Serial.

Some relevant members of GUI:

```
QPushButton pushButton;
int itemNumber;
```

Relevant members of Serial:

```
void send(int number)
```

When GUI's member pushButton is clicked, I want to pass GUI's member 'pushButton' as the argument to the function Serial::send(int number).  I see one option of doing something like

```
connect(GUI,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(customSlot()));
```

in my MainWindow function.  However, then I don't know which item in my vector it came from, so I don't know which itemNumber to grab (they're all different).

I also thought maybe I'd do it in the GUI class, but that doesn't have access to the Serial::send(int number) method.  I don't want a Serial object in each GUI, because it just won't work that way at this point.

How can I pass information from the child object GUI up to the parent object MainWindow from a signal?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `QSignalMapper`?  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html

Comment: Another possible way to do it:  subclass QPushButton, and have the subclass declare both a clicked(int) signal and a userClickedMe() slot.  Have it connect its clicked() signal to its userClickedMe() slot, and have userClickedMe() do an "emit clicked(myNumber)".  Now your main GUI code can connect the button-subclass's clicked(int) to its slot in the way you wanted.

Comment: @RA. This is a great way! Thanks for pointing me to the QSignalMapper class, that will be very useful!

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I also like this idea. This would allow me to pass more information, which I think may be required in other areas of this project. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Use `QObject::sender()` function inside a slot to get the object witch sent a signal.
Of course, you need some appropriate cast method:

```
void someSlot() {
    QPushButton *sender = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender()); 
    ...
}
```